# Pyspark - groupby with filter - Optimizing speed

Tags: python, pyspark

I have billions of rows to process using Pyspark.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
category    value    flag
   A          10       1
   A          12       0
   B          15       0
and so on...
```

I need to run two groupby operations: one on rows where flag==1 and other for ALL rows. Currently I am doing this:

```
frame_1 = df.filter(df.flag==1).groupBy('category').agg(F.sum('value').alias('foo1'))
frame_2 = df.groupBy('category').agg(F.sum('value').alias(foo2))
final_frame = frame1.join(frame2,on='category',how='left')
```

As of now this code is running, but my problem is that it is very slow.
Is there a way to improve this code in terms of speed or this is the limit because I understand lazy evaluation by PySpark does take some time, but is this code the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can avoid the expensive join and achieve this using one `groupBy`.

```
final_frame_2 = df.groupBy("category").agg(
    F.sum(F.col("value")*F.col("flag")).alias("foo1"),
    F.sum(F.col("value")).alias("foo2"),
)
final_frame_2.show()
#+--------+----+----+
#|category|foo1|foo2|
#+--------+----+----+
#|       B| 0.0|15.0|
#|       A|10.0|22.0|
#+--------+----+----+
```

Now compare the execution plans:

First your method:

```
final_frame.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*(5) Project [category#0, foo1#68, foo2#75]
#+- SortMergeJoin [category#0], [category#78], LeftOuter
#   :- *(2) Sort [category#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
#   :  +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[category#0], functions=[sum(cast(value#1 as double))])
#   :     +- Exchange hashpartitioning(category#0, 200)
#   :        +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[category#0], functions=[partial_sum(cast(value#1 as double))])
#   :           +- *(1) Project [category#0, value#1]
#   :              +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(flag#2) && (cast(flag#2 as int) = 1))
#   :                 +- Scan ExistingRDD[category#0,value#1,flag#2]
#   +- *(4) Sort [category#78 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
#      +- *(4) HashAggregate(keys=[category#78], functions=[sum(cast(value#79 as double))])
#         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(category#78, 200)
#            +- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[category#78], functions=[partial_sum(cast(value#79 as double))])
#               +- *(3) Project [category#78, value#79]
#                  +- Scan ExistingRDD[category#78,value#79,flag#80]
```

Now the same for `final_frame_2`:

```
final_frame_2.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*(2) HashAggregate(keys=[category#0], functions=[sum((cast(value#1 as double) * cast(flag#2 as double))), sum(cast(value#1 as double))])
#+- Exchange hashpartitioning(category#0, 200)
#   +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[category#0], functions=[partial_sum((cast(value#1 as double) * cast(flag#2 as double))), partial_sum(cast(value#1 as double))])
#      +- Scan ExistingRDD[category#0,value#1,flag#2]
```

**Note**: Strictly speaking, this is not the *exact* same output as the example you gave (shown below) because your inner join will eliminate all categories where there is no row with `flag = 1`.

```
final_frame.show()
#+--------+----+----+
#|category|foo1|foo2|
#+--------+----+----+
#|       A|10.0|22.0|
#+--------+----+----+
```

You can add an aggregation to sum `flag` and filter those where the sum is zero if that's a requirement, with only a minor hit to performance.

```
final_frame_3 = df.groupBy("category").agg(
    F.sum(F.col("value")*F.col("flag")).alias("foo1"),
    F.sum(F.col("value")).alias("foo2"),
    F.sum(F.col("flag")).alias("foo3")
).where(F.col("foo3")!=0).drop("foo3")

final_frame_3.show()
#+--------+----+----+
#|category|foo1|foo2|
#+--------+----+----+
#|       A|10.0|22.0|
#+--------+----+----+
```

Comment: You are a true genius!

Comment: The way you suggested would for aggregation methods like sum etc. Is there any way to achieve this for methods like countDistinct() ? @pault

Comment: @pault, similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62335895/pyspark-groupby-filter-and-find-min-value) and trying to use your methods, here.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that a join operation is expensive.
You can just do this and add flag to your groups:

```
frame_1 = df.groupBy(["category", "flag"]).agg(F.sum('value').alias('foo1'))
```

if you have more than two flags and you want to do `flag == 1 vs the rest` then:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
frame_1 = df.withColumn("flag2", F.when(F.col("flag") == 1, 1).otherwise(0))
frame_1 = df.groupBy(["category", "flag2"]).agg(F.sum('value').alias('foo1'))
```

if you want to do a groupby apply for all rows, just make a new frame where you do another roll up for category:

`frame_1 = df.groupBy("category").agg(F.sum('foo1').alias('foo2'))`

it is not possible to do both in one step, because essentially there is a group overlap.